# How do I fill in a loginForm using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to fill in a loginForm using BeautifulSoup (I know it's not the easiest way) but I don't know how I can do that. Here under the loginForm.

```
    <form id="loginForm" class="loginContainer" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/wipb2bweb/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=C647FBABEB8C4ADC3DCCA3C6C875BECC.prod1" method="post"><fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>

            <img src="/wipb2bweb/_ui/themes/carhartt/images/loginTitle.png"
                alt="Login" class="title" />

            <form>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="User"><img
                        src="/wipb2bweb/_ui/themes/carhartt/images/loginLabelUser_de.png"
                        alt="Benutzername" />
                    </label>
                    <input id="User" name="j_username" type="text" value=""/></div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="Password"><img
                        src="/wipb2bweb/_ui/themes/carhartt/images/loginLabelPass_de.png"
                        alt="Passwort" />
                    </label>
                    <input id="Password" name="j_password" type="password" value=""/></div>
                <input type="submit" class="hiddenSubmit"/>
                <a href="#" title="Login" class="btnGreyTextured">
                    <span>Login</span>
                </a>
            </form>
```

Comment: Actually with BeautifulSoup you can't "fill the form" as a normal action on a guy, but to do something similar you need to sniff or analyze the traffic and send an HTTP POST request with the form's data. In your case your probably need to send a requesto to the url: yoursiteurl//wipb2bweb/j_spring_security_check;jsessionid=C647FBABEB8C4ADC3DCCA3C6C875BECC.prod1 with some payload compiled based on the request I told you to analyze before.

Comment: For the network analyzer on Firefox press CTRL+MAIUS+C (or right click and select 'Inspect Element') and after go on the 'Network' Tab. Now you might compile your form and press the Login button and see the how the packet is being structured

Comment: BeautifulSoup is used for Web Scrapping. If you want to interact with the Browser go with Selenium, used for automating web browsers.